# How to select rows in google sheets by condition

Tags: google-sheets-query

I've been researching this for a couple of hours now and have had no luck.

I am trying to search for emails in my spreadsheet that contain "@google.com" and have them all selected so that I can copy them instead of going through them 1 by 1. There are around 90K so this would be a considerable undertaking.

This is the formula that I am currently using:

```
=QUERY(Data!A:A,"select A where(A =@google.com)")
```

All of the data is in column A.

Hope I've just made a dumb error somewhere.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps what you might try is:

```
=QUERY(Data!A:A,"where A contains '@google.com'")
```